# Is it possible to use both a converter AND a StringFormat in WPF MultiBinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding, string-formatting, imultivalueconverter

I am using the following MultiBinding. The converter outputs an int and the expected output of the MultiBinding is something like "SomeText|123". The Bindings and converter work fine, but the StringFormat doesn't seem to be applied - I just get the int value that the converter outputs. Is it possible to apply the StringFormat to the IMultiValueConverter's output?

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}"
              StringFormat="SomeText|{}{0}">
    <Binding />
    <Binding Path="SomePath" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you format your string in the converter? I dont think that both is possible.

Comment: See my answer below - I have figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was binding to a property of type object. by changing this to a string property the stringformat was used as expected.

Comment: trying to do the same but unfortunately i'm stuck with a non string content and the converter is variable multibindings and parameters